# Fetching data from <span> tag in flutter

Tags: html, flutter, http, dart, flutter2.0

I am trying to fetch live gold prices from a website using this code.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;

getWebData() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      "https://www.mcxindia.com/en/market-data/get-quote/FUTCOM/GOLD/05FEB2021"));
  dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
  print(document);
  var element = document.getElementById("litPrice");
}
```

I know how to fetch text when it's between `<a>` tag or `<p>` tag but in this case, it's just between a `<span>` tag which looks like
`<span id="litPrice">47526</span>` I am unable to figure out how to get this number.

[html pub dev](https://pub.dev/packages/html)
[http pub dev](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

Answer (score 0):

The method would be the same as in the case of the `<a>` and `<p>` tags. The text between tags is available via `element.innerHtml`

I think the issue you're running into is that the tag you're selecting isn't present in the document returned from that url. In the browser, that element is inserted into the document via javascript after the document is loaded.

There are a couple of ways you could deal with this:

1. Use an API - If the service you're trying to access provides a REST API, then you can see if the data you're trying to access is available via that route. This is by far the better way, if it's available.
2. Use a headless browser - This is a really heavy-weight solution, and likely won't work for your use case, but I'll put it here as one of the possibilities anyway. In dart, you can use the [puppeteer](https://pub.dev/packages/puppeteer) library to interact with a headless chrome browser. This way, you can load the page, wait for the scripts to run, then scrape the DOM - you should then find the element you're looking for.

Comment: I tried `element.innerHtml` but its not printing anything but `element.outerHtml` is giving `<span id="litPrice"></span>` not sure why.